# SAML Authentication for a .NET Application

Tags: c#, .net, saml

It should be possible to use SAML to authenticate users for any type of application (according to the spec), but the examples I have seen are cookie-based ASP.NET web-sites.

Does anyone know of an example authenticating users for, say, a Win Forms app (not using cookies)?

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure what it is you are looking for. If you are looking for SAML based authentication, you can use some combination of Windows Identity Framework and WCF and AD FS. SAML is just the "language" of authentication, but unless you already have an identity provider, you need to start there first.

You can use this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335707.aspx) to give you an idea of what the basic infrastructure looks like, and I frequently use the site [leastprivilege.com](http://www.leastprivilege.com/) for a deeper reference.

But, if the scope of your application is purely within the desktop (ie, never communicates with any services) you really don't need anything like SAML to achieve your goal. Usage of tokens like SAML are for communicating with web services where the endpoints trust the identity provider.

Answer (score 0):

SAML is a wee complicated beastie. I'm not sure I'd try to roll my own SAML SSO solution.

When we implemented SAML SSO, we used [PingFederate](http://www.pingidentity.com/) from. It's expensive, but good. There's also some open source SAML SSO stuff about, but I can't really speak to it.

PingFederate is pretty dead simple to configure and use, although if you don't speak SAML, the learning curve will be steep until you understand the concepts, the flow and the lingo used.

Comment: Somehow PingFederate page responds with 403 error and some half-scary sounding info as if entering the page was an attempt to breach their security. However the page opens up fine using a proxy. Could it be that they block users from certain countries?